# Algorithms for connecting edges of rectangles

Tags: algorithm, trigonometry

I can't think of a way to connect the edges of a rectangle like: [image]

By what value do I shift the original mid point by to transform into the red line (connecting the edges instead of the midpoint)?

Comment: create a vector from midpoint to midpoint. Find the intersections of this vector with the rectangle lines. Then calculate delta x and delta y for this zwo points (subtract them) and that will give you how much you has to move the coordinates of the rectangle. Sorry it is some work but that is math :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you know the height and width of the rectangles (and the angle theta).
Based on this, you can just use simple trigonometry:

Y has to be shifted by height/2 upwards (really easy to see, so won't prove it)

For X, drop a vertical from the end of the array to a horizontal line parallel to the edges (the line with which theta is formed).

tan(theta) = y/x which means x = y/tan(theta). You know y is just height/2, and you know the value of theta, so just plug those values in

**EDIT:** Just realized, stack overflow doesn't render TeX so I removed the TeX encoding...

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to see if there was a single algorithm without if loops that encodes all possibilities (for example, if the boxes were parallel, I won't be moving y by height/2 but x by width/2), but I guess I have to find the theta and then shift correspondingly

Comment: Yes, if you want to, I can edit my answer for general cases (assuming I have the height, width and the angle)

Comment: Hey, sorry, was kinda busy... The easiest way to do this for a general case is rotate your second rectangle about the midpoint so that its sides are parallel to the first rectangle. After doing this, find the corner using the aforementioned steps. Now just rotate it back to your original position and you will be done... I don't think its complicated enough to change the answer, so I hope a comment suffices

Comment: Just as a note though, it might be better to ask such questions on stack.math rather than stack overflow